# Calling overloaded constructors

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to apply some spring boot code to a legacy project from my work, the problem is that some classes have overloaded constructors and I don't know how to call them using spring boot:

The code looks like this:

```
@Component
ClassA {

    public void doSomething() {
        int a;
        SomeObjectB b;

        ClassB classB = null;

        classB = new ClassB(a, ab, b);
    }

}

@Service
classB {

    @Autowired
    private ClassC classC;

    classB(int a, SomeObjectA a) {
        //Logic with parameters
    }

    classB(int a, SomeObjectB b) {
        //Some logic
        classC.someMethod(b)
        //More logic
    }

    classB(int a, SomeObjectC c) {
        //Logic with parameters
    }
}

@Component
ClassC {

    public void someMethod(SomeObjectB b) {

    }
}
```

Within the class ClassA, the classB I'm trying to call is instantiated doing `classB = new ClassB(a, ab, b);` therefore the autowired class ClassC is null since is out of the spring context. I have tried to implement a factory method with prototype scope in order to create a new Bean every time the class is called, however is not working as expected.

This is what I've got so far:

```
@Component
ClassA {

    @Autowired
    private Function<String, ClassB> myPrototypeFactory;

    public void doSomething() {
        int a;
        SomeObjectB b;

        Map myMap = new HashMap<>();
        myMap.put("a", a);
        myMap.put("b", b);

        myPrototypeFactory.apply(myMap);
    }

}

@Configuration
ConfigurationClass {

    @Bean
    public Function<Map<String, Object>, ClassB> myPrototypeFactory() {
        return map -> {
                return myObjectPrototype((int)map.get("a"), (SomeObjectB)map.get("b"));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public ClassB myObjectPrototype(int a, SomeObjectB b) {
        return new ClassB(a, b);
    }

}
```

So the question is, How do I call an overloaded constructor from ClassB in order to avoid nulls in the @Autowired fields? This is the first time I face this kind of problem.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: If it's got autowired fields and the @service annotation, you shouldn't be calling _any_ constructor and instead let spring manage the lifecycle of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take bean from application context by passing beanName, agruments... If there is multiple constructor then u need to define ClassB `prototype` not `singleton`..

```
@Service
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
classB {

    @Autowired
    private ClassC classC;

    classB(int a, SomeObjectA a) {
        //Logic with parameters
    }

    classB(int a, SomeObjectB b) {
        //Some logic
        classC.someMethod(b)
        //More logic
    }

    classB(int a, SomeObjectC c) {
        //Logic with parameters
    }
}

@Component
ClassA {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    public void doSomething() {
        int a;
        SomeObjectB b;

        ClassB classB = null;
        classB = (ClassB) applicationContext.getBean("classB", a, ab);
    }

}
```